# set all neighboring array items equal to 1 if adjacent to nonzero value

Tags: python

I am looking for an efficient way to set all array indexes neighboring a non-zero value equal to 1.  So for example, if I have an array called `arr` that looks like the following:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.zeros((5,5))
arr[1,1] = arr[2,2] = arr[3,3] = arr[0,5] = 1

arr
# array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
#        [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Is there an easy way to get array called `arr2` that keeps all non-zero values, but also sets left/right and up/down neighbors to non-zero values equal to 1?  So in this small reproducible example, I would like a result that looks like:

```
arr2
# array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
#        [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
#        [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

Diagonal neighbors aren't considered.

Comment: You can do this pretty easily with a loop and simple arithmetic.

Comment: This is more of a logistical challenge than a coding question, i dont think this is the right place to ask, sorry!

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_dilation.html#scipy.ndimage.binary_dilation

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments (@Code-Apprentice), here is what I was able to work out.  Doesn't seem very 'pythonic' (i.e., elegant), but alas, it gets the job done.  I was thinking there was a simpler alternative to the brute-force method for much larger 'real world' applications.

```
arr = np.zeros((5,5))
arr[1,1] = arr[2,2] = arr[3,3] = arr[0,4] = 1

arr2 = arr.copy()
for i in np.arange(0, arr.shape[0]):
    for j in np.arange(0, arr.shape[1]):
        im1 = i - 1
        ip1 = i + 1
        jm1 = j - 1
        jp1 = j + 1

        if(im1 >= 0):
            if(arr[i, j] == 1 and arr[im1, j] == 0):
                arr2[im1, j] = 1

        if(ip1 < arr.shape[0]):
            if(arr[i, j] == 1 and arr[ip1, j] == 0):
                arr2[ip1, j] = 1

        if(jm1 >= 0):
            if(arr[i, j] == 1 and arr[i, jm1] == 0):
                arr2[i, jm1] = 1

        if(jp1 < arr.shape[1]):
            if(arr[i, j] == 1 and arr[i, jp1] == 0):
                arr2[i, jp1] = 1
```